# Unable to connect via jira-python

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

Racking my brain over this.  Just signed up here because I was having so much trouble with this.  Here is my super simple code:

```
from jira.client import JIRA
jira_user='username'
jira_pass='password' 
jira_server='https://jira-01:8443'

jira_options = {'server': jira_server, 'verify': False}
jira = JIRA(options=jira_options, basic_auth=(jira_user, jira_pass))
```

When executing, I get this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "jira1.py", line 12, in <module>
 jira = JIRA(options=jira_options, basic_auth=(jira_user, jira_pass))
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 219, in __init__  
si = self.server_info()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 1504, in server_info
return self._get_json('serverInfo')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 1894, in _get_json
  r = self._session.get(url, params=params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jira/resilientsession.py", line 78, in get
return self.__verb('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jira/resilientsession.py", line 63, in __verb
r = method(url, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 477, in get
return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 341, in _make_request
self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 761, in _validate_conn
conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 238, in connect
ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 279, in ssl_wrap_socket
 cnx.set_tlsext_host_name(server_hostname)
AttributeError: '_socketobject' object has no attribute 'set_tlsext_host_name'
```

The same thing happens if I remove `'verify': False`

I know I can access the API and this user has permissions because I can hit it correctly with curl and get the right results.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by reinstalling python-requests via yum.

Comment: please mark this as solved or delete the question so that it does not show up as unanswered anymore.